# Inheritance without "extends" keyword in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

Is it possible to inherit a class without using extends keyword  in Java ?

Comment: All classes extend from Object. All **enum** types extend from `java.lang.Enum` class. In both cases. `extends` keyword is not used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Every class extends `Object`, whether you add `extends Object` to the declaration or not.

There are also [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), such as

```
Foo foo = new Foo(){
    // some method implemented in here.
};
```

which can extend a class without `extends`.

Comment: You can also add that "enum types extend from `java.lang.Enum` class"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Each class extend the `Object` by default without declaration.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said on this thread all classes extend from Object.

So it does exist, however this is not something which you can control without using the extends keyword. I don't think that you will ever need to, if you do maybe we should discuss that specific situation.